# imapfilter - does a mailbox exist

Tags: imap, lua

Sorry bit of a imapfilter 101 I'm afraid ... I'm trying to do something quite simple. I seems to be making heavy weather of it, feels like there's a simple solution.

I want to process inbox into new and read . Now the first time this script is run "new" and "read" will not exist.

I did:

```
external:create_mailbox("new")
```

But got "error" messages on stdout/stderr
imapfilter: IMAP (3): 1007 NO [ALREADYEXISTS] Mailbox already exists (0.001 + 0.000 secs).

...tried:

```
local success, data = pcall(external.create_mailbox, external, "new")
```

But I guess these are not "errors" in the LUA sense , simply messages, so I want something of the form:

```
if external.mailbox.new exists
 ....
else
  create it and do some setup
end
```

(I know, in this specific case I could simply set options.create = true ...but let's imagine I want to do some special processing for the "does not exist case")